# Annihilaor of a prime is non-zero

Tags: ring-theory

If we have a commutative noetherian ring how do we know that the annihilator of a prime ideal is always non-zero?

Comment: Unless you mean something other than what I would mean by this (ie, the set of elements in the ring which give $0$ when multiplied by anything in the ideal), then we don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annihilator of any nonzero prime ideal of $\Bbb Z$ is zero. (If you clarify that you mean something else by annihilator, i can delete this. I'm just answering based on the standard definition.)

Comment: Thanks, I had made a mistake. What I was looking at had prime ideals with no-regular elements and hence there would have to be a non-zero annihilator but I was overlooking that and getting confused. Thanks for the answer anyway